# Laravel: store in session and retrive in blade

Tags: php, laravel

Im very new in laravel so please if you have solution write it with code from my example code,
All I want just how to store data in session and retrive it in any page of my project, please I need you to help me by writing route,function and code in blade if needed becuase im very new in laravel
**I have form in home page**

```
 <form id="booking-form">
 <input type="text" id="car" name="car" >
  <a href="{{ route('car.dashboard') }}">check car</a>
</form>
```

**route**

```
Route::get('/car/dashboard', 'HomeController@index')->name('car.dashboard');
```

**function**

```
 public function index()
 {
  return view('index.car.cardashboard');
  }
```

so I want to display input car in page cardashboard

**cardashboard.blade.php**

```
 <label id='car'></label>
```

Comment: Your form is wrong. It won't post any data since you are just redirecting to another link

Comment: read [here](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html) for forms